# Eclipse : set hotkey for up/down/left/right key

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

I very love emacs hotkey for up/down/left/right : `Control + N, Control + P, Control + B, Control + F` respectively. So, I want to bring this to Eclipse, but not all hotkey of emacs. (Because in Eclipse, there is an option that using emacs hotkey).

In Eclipse, I go into : `[Windows]\[Preferences]\[Key]`. But, I don't know which category to change this. Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the categories:

- up: Line Up
- down: Line Down
- right: Next Column
- left: Previous Column

Make sure to check the "Editing Text" option for the "When" field and also clear any possible Conflicts (e.g. 'Ctrl + F' is by default used for finding text).